# What resource could I use to build a one channel only Android TV App

Tags: android-studio, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have spent many hours searching but have not been able to find what should I use to build an app in Android Studio that allow me  to show in Google TV just one channel

I want my TV station to have an app so people can find us on chromecast when searching for my channel

We already have the app for android phones working but for TVs I have had a hard time looking for the best way to accomplish the project.

Do I use exoplayer, or leanback or unity or go the Googles input service way ?  suggestion  and guidance appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the Android TV API

Comment: Yes I have looked at it but not sure if it would work because they are more geared  to work as an app, , not just for watching a single tv channel